# How can i open holograph activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, charts, pie-chart

I'm trying to click in a button situated in my MainActivity and open the activity with a pie chart using holograph library.. The problem is that the holograph sample is structured with fragments and no activities.. This is the pie fragment: EDITED

```
    public class grafico extends Activity {
    public View onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container) {
        final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.piegrafico, container, false);
        PieGraph pg = (PieGraph)v.findViewById(R.id.piegraph);
        PieSlice slice = new PieSlice();
        slice.setColor(Color.parseColor("#99CC00"));
        slice.setValue(2);
        pg.addSlice(slice);
        slice = new PieSlice();
        slice.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFBB33"));
        slice.setValue(10);
        pg.addSlice(slice);
        slice = new PieSlice();
        slice.setColor(Color.parseColor("#AA66CC"));
        slice.setValue(2);
        pg.addSlice(slice);     

        pg.setOnSliceClickedListener(new OnSliceClickedListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(int index) {

            }

        });

        return v;
    }
}
```

and my button in MainActivity:

```
public void graph(View view) 
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, grafico.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

button in main.xml:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/grafico"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="grafico"
        android:text="grafico" />
```

the logcat says:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method grafico(View) in the activity
---
---
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: grafico [class android.view.View]
```

so i think the problem is that the grafico activity is a fragment.. How can i solve?

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems here. First of all, your `grafico` class doesn't extend `Activity`. You need to extend `Activity` in order for it to be able to be launched by an Intent. Second of all, you probably shouldn't override `onCreateView()`, it's usually better practice to override the `onCreate()` method of `Activity`. If you are in need of further clarification, please ask.

Comment: try to see my edit please.. dowsn't go again.. i don't know if maybe the problem is the button..

Comment: ok, i was wrong before.. sorry..my fault. onClick is `grafico` and my public void was `graph`.. anyway the activity is blank :(

Comment: You need to create a method called `public void grafico(View v)` in your grafico class. the `onClick` XML attribute of a `Button` specifies the name of a method that will be called when the button is pressed. Right now your `onClick` method is specified as `grafico`, but no such method exists in your class. On top of that, I would change your class name to `Grafico`, as class names are usually done in camel case with the first letter capitalized; additionally, change your method name for `onClick` to something other than `grafico`, because that is the same function as the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to override onCreateView() instead oncreate(). It may solve your problem. Thanks